# Significato di "volgere in gioco" in questo contesto

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Il barone rampante*, di Italo Calvino, ho letto:

> La Marchesa arrivò. Come sempre, la gelosia di lui le fece piacere: un po' la incitò, un po' la **volse in gioco**. Così tornarono le belle giornate d'amore e mio fratello era felice.

La mia domanda è sul significato dell'espressione "volgere in gioco" che appare in questo brano. Nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/gioco/) ho trovato che vuol dire "volgere in scherzo". Tuttavia, non capisco molto bene cosa sarebbe questo "volgere in scherzo" in questo contesto. Significa che la gelosia di lui le faceva fare scherzi?

Comment: Quello che forse potrebbe non essere chiaro è che in “un po' la incitò, un po' la volse in gioco” il soggetto dei due verbi è la Marchesa e il complemento oggetto (“la”) è la gelosia.

Comment: Hai ragione, @DaG: non avevo interpretato bene il soggetto e il complemento oggetto della frase. Con questo chiarimento mi è più chiaro il senso.

Comment: Quindi, la Marchesa un po' incitò la gelosia, un po' trasformò la gelosia in gioco.

Comment: Precisamente, @Charo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il significato corretto è quello che hai trovato tu ma il concetto è che la Marchesa non aveva voglia di fare scherzi ma
trasformò la gelosia in scherzo, in gioco.

Comment: Penso che non sia chiaro che la frase citata significhi che la Marchesa "cercò di sdrammatizzare la situazione per far tornare un clima familiare mite".

Comment: Secondo me, è necessario togliere questo per poter accettare la risposta.

Comment: Suggerimento condivisibile. Risposta modificata.